# Unused arguments in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to have a the software ignore the fact that there are unused arguments defined when a module is run?

For example, I have a module `multiply(a,b)`, which returns the product of `a` and `b`.  I will receive an error if I call the module like so:

```
multiply(a=20,b=30,c=10)
```

Returning an error on this just seems a bit unnecessary, since the required inputs `a` and `b` have been specified.  Is it possible to avoid this bad behaviour?

An easy solution would be just to stop specifying `c`, but that doesn't answer why R behaves like this.  Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: In response to "Returning an error on this just seems a bit unnecessary", I don't think this is unnecessary, as you are clearly expecting something for assigning the additional argument you need to be told that argument does not exist to prevent "unexpected behavior" of the function.

Comment: First, it's a function not a module.  Second, how does your function know what to do with the additional arguments?  I think the answer is correct, but it should be more illustrative of how one would actually use the dots (aka "...").

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Change the definition of multiply to take additional unknown arguments:

```
multiply <- function(a, b, ...) {
  # Original code
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The R.utils package has a function called doCall which is like do.call, but it does not return an error if unused arguments are passed.

```
multiply <- function(a, b) a * b

# these will fail
multiply(a = 20, b = 30, c = 10)
# Error in multiply(a = 20, b = 30, c = 10) : unused argument (c = 10)
do.call(multiply, list(a = 20, b = 30, c = 10))
# Error in (function (a, b)  : unused argument (c = 10)

# R.utils::doCall will work
R.utils::doCall(multiply, args = list(a = 20, b = 30, c = 10))
# [1] 600
# it also does not require the arguments to be passed as a list
R.utils::doCall(multiply, a = 20, b = 30, c = 10)
# [1] 600
```

Answer (score 9):

One approach (which I can't imagine is good programming practice) is to add the `...` which is traditionally used to pass arguments specified in one function to another.

```
> multiply <- function(a,b) a*b
> multiply(a = 2,b = 4,c = 8)
Error in multiply(a = 2, b = 4, c = 8) : unused argument(s) (c = 8)
> multiply2 <- function(a,b,...) a*b
> multiply2(a = 2,b = 4,c = 8)
[1] 8
```

You can read more about `...` is intended to be used [here](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r)

Comment: Why do you think this would be bad practice? (Not disagreeing, just curious.) I feel like I've read lots of R documentation where the `...` argument is simply ignored, which suggests people do this from time to time.

Comment: ... is intended to pass to sub-functions, particularly methods, where the required (or accepted) list of arguments is not known at the time when the function is written.  If you do pass the ... downward, you'll get the "unused argument" error at a deeper level.  In general, not knowing whether you are or are not using an argument leads to confusion.

Comment: And it just hit me that I do this often enough with C++ virtual methods.  The argument list is of course fixed, but some object methods do not need all of the arguments.

Comment: @joran - honestly haven't put *too* much thought into it, just seems like you could get yourself mighty confused down the road if you use this function as an input to other functions and that unused argument is now used for something. You are right though that several of the R docs do have something to the effect of `... is ignored for now` so maybe I'm over thinking things.

Answer (score 7):

You could use dots: `...` in your function definition.

```
myfun <- function(a, b, ...){
  cat(a,b)
}

myfun(a=4,b=7,hello=3)

# 4 7
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you. I had a long list of arguments, most of which were irrelevant. I didn't want to hard code them in.  This is what I came up with

```
library(magrittr)
do_func_ignore_things <- function(data, what){
    acceptable_args <- data[names(data) %in% (formals(what) %>% names)]
    do.call(what, acceptable_args %>% as.list)
}

do_func_ignore_things(c(n = 3, hello = 12, mean = -10), "rnorm")
# -9.230675 -10.503509 -10.927077
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there are already a number of answers directly addressing the question, and R is often used by technically skilled non-programmers, let me quickly outline why the error exists, and advise against suppression workarounds.

The number of parameters is an important aspect defining a function. If the number of parameters mismatches, that's a good indication that there is a mismatch between the callers intent and what the function is about to do. For this reason, this would be a compilation error in many programming languages, including Java, Python, Haskell, and many others. Indeed, stricter type checking in many of these languages will also cause errors if types mismatch.

As a program grows in size, and code ages, it becomes harder to spot whether mismatches of this kind are intended or are genuine bugs. This is why an idea of "clean code" - simple to read code with no errors or warnings - is often a standard professional programmers work towards.

Accordingly, I recommend reworking the code to remove the unnecessary parameter. It will be simpler to understand and debug for yourself and others in the future.

Of course I understand that R users are often working on small scripts with limited lifespans, and the usual tradeoffs of large software engineering projects don't always apply. Maybe for your quick script, that will only be used for a week, it made sense to just suppress the error. However, it is widely observed (and I have seen in my own experience) that what code endures is rarely obvious at the time of writing. If you are pursuing open science, and publishing your code and data, it is especially helpful for that code to be useful in the future, to others, so they can reproduce your results.

Answer (score 1):

A similar error is also thrown when using the `select()` function from the `dplyr` package and having loaded the `MASS` package too.
Minimal sample to reproduce:

```
library("dplyr") 
library("MASS") 
iris %>% select(Species)
```

will throw:

```
Error in select(., Species) : unused argument (Species)
```

To circumvent use:

```
library("dplyr") 
library("MASS")
iris %>% dplyr::select(Species)
```

**EXPLANATION**:
When loading `dplyr`, a `select` function is defined and when loading `MASS` afterwards, the `select` function is overwritten. When the `select` function is called, `MASS::select()` is executed which needs a different number of arguments.

Comment: It can happen in every overlap between two packages; for example, I had it when I tried `distance()` with both "Gmisc" and "psych" loaded. The leading "tell" was running `?distance` and getting: "Help on topic 'distance' was found in the following packages:"

Answer (score -1):

R has a function prod() which does multiplication really well. The example the asker gave works fine with the prod() function without returning an error.`

```
prod(a=20,b=30,c=10)

 # 6000
```

In any case, an error highlighted is an opportunity to rectify it, so not a bad behaviour.

Comment: True, but I think they were just using the multiplication function as a simple example, not because they specifically needed a way to multiply numbers