# Apply function to data.table using function's character name and arguments as character vector

Tags: r, data.table, do.call

I would like to call functions by their character name on a data.table. Each function has also a vector of arguments (so there is a long list of functions to apply to data.table). Arguments are data.table columns. My first thought was that do.call would be a good approach for that task. Here is a simple example with one function name to run and it's vector of columns to pass:

```
# set up dummy data 
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(x = rep(c("a","b"),each=5), y = sample(10), z = sample(10))
# columns to use as function arguments
mycols <- c('y','z')
# function name 
func <- 'sum'
# my current solution:
DT[, do.call(func, list(get('y'), get('z'))), by = x]
#    x V1
# 1: a 47
# 2: b 63
```

I am not satisfied with that since it requires to name specifically each column. And I would like to pass just a character vector `mycols`.

Other solution that works just as I need in this case is:

```
DT[, do.call(func, .SD), .SDcols = mycols, by = x]
```

But there is a hiccup with custom functions and the only solution that works for me is the first one:

```
#own dummy function    
myfunc <- function(arg1, arg2){
  arg1+arg2
}
func <- 'myfunc'
DT[, do.call(func, list(get('y'), get('z'))), by = x] 
#   x V1
#  1: a  6
#  2: a  6
#  3: a 11
#  4: a 17
#  5: a  7
#  6: b 15
#  7: b 17
#  8: b 10
#  9: b 11
# 10: b 10
# second solution does not work 
DT[, do.call(func, .SD), .SDcols = mycols, by = x]
# Error in myfunc(y = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L), z = c(3L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 5L)) : 
#  unused arguments (y = c(3, 4, 5, 7, 2), z = c(3, 2, 6, 10, 5))
```

As I understand it, it assumes that myfunc has arguments `y, z` which is not true. There should be variables `y,z` which should be passed to arguments `arg1, arg2`.

I also tried mget function, but also with no success:

```
DT[, do.call(func, mget(mycols)), by = x] 
# Error: value for ‘y’ not found
```

I could be missing something fairly obvious, thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I would go with `call` or `as.call` instead of `do.call`, it needs to be wrapper into `eval` but gives some more flexibility. Something like `eval(as.call(list(func, as.name("y"), as.name("z"))))`.

Comment: @jangorecki Yes, this `DT[, eval(call(func, as.name("y"), as.name("z"))), by = x]` works for me as well. But I would like to use character vector `mycols` instead of naming explicitly `y` and `z`.

Comment: Are you looking for something  like `DT[, Reduce(func, mget(mycols)), by = x]`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto That is very close to what I am looking for. For some reason if you define a custom function with more than 2 arguments your solution throws an error `Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : argument "arg3" is missing, with no default`. Any ideas?

Comment: @wasyl, Your question seems quite similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33911393/1270695). Perhaps my answer there might help.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Ok, Reduce requires a binary function (i.e. a function of two variables). I am afraid I can not always satisfy that condition in all my custom functions that I want to apply to data.table. Thank you for the solution anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unused arguments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270397/unused-arguments-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing something (well, it's not really obvious, but careful debugging of the error identifies the problem). Your function expects named arguments `arg1` and `arg2`. You are passing it arguments `y = ...` and `z = ...` via `do.call` (which you have noticed). The solution is to pass the list without names:

```
> DT[, do.call(func, unname(.SD[, mycols, with = F])), by = x]
    x V1
 1: a  6
 2: a  6
 3: a 11
 4: a 17
 5: a  7
 6: b 15
 7: b 17
 8: b 10
 9: b 11
10: b 10
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be dependent on the types of functions you want to use, but it seems like `Reduce` might be of interest to you.

Here it is with both of your examples:

```
mycols <- c('y','z')
func <- 'sum'

DT[, Reduce(func, mget(mycols)), by = x]
#    x V1
# 1: a 47
# 2: b 63

myfunc <- function(arg1, arg2){
  arg1+arg2
}
func <- 'myfunc'

DT[, Reduce(func, mget(mycols)), by = x]
#     x V1
#  1: a  6
#  2: a  6
#  3: a 11
#  4: a 17
#  5: a  7
#  6: b 15
#  7: b 17
#  8: b 10
#  9: b 11
# 10: b 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that helped me to achieve what I want.

```
func <- 'sum'
mycols <- c('y','z')
DT[, do.call(func, lapply(mycols, function(x) get(x))), by = x]
#    x V1
# 1: a 47
# 2: b 63
```

One can pass to it `base` functions or custom defined functions (not so specific as with `Reduce` solution).

Comment: all you are doing here is to return a list without names... you are much better off just using `unname`.