# R: How can I make a function with a function input with data.table

Tags: r, function, input, data.table

I faced a problem when exercising with data.table. Here is my problem. I wrote a simple subtraction function:

```
minus <- function(a, b){
      return(a - b)
  }
```

My dataset is a simple data.table:

```
dt <- as.data.table(data.frame(first=c(5, 6, 7), second=c(1,2,3)))
dt
  first second
1     5      1
2     6      2
3     7      3
```

I would like to write another function,

```
myFunc <- function(dt, FUN, ...){
      return(dt[, new := FUN(...)])
  }
```

The usage is simply:

```
res <- myFunc(dt, minus, first, second)
```

and the result would be the following:

```
res
   first second new
1:     5      1   4
2:     6      2   4
3:     7      3   4
```

How can I archive such a goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way, but you can try something like this:

```
myFunc <- function(indt, FUN, ...) {
  FUN <- deparse(substitute(FUN))    # Get FUN as a string
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)              # Match it to an existing function
  dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]  # Get the rest of the stuff
  # I've used `copy(indt)` so that it doesn't affect your original dataset
  copy(indt)[, new := Reduce(FUN, mget(sapply(dots, deparse)))][]
}
```

(Note that this is very specific to how you've created your `minus()` function.)

Here it is in action:

```
res <- myFunc(dt, minus, first, second)
dt  ## Unchanged
#    first second
# 1:     5      1
# 2:     6      2
# 3:     7      3

res
#    first second new
# 1:     5      1   4
# 2:     6      2   4
# 3:     7      3   4
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I would like to change the new column name based on input?

Comment: @Nal-rA, maybe use `setnames`?

Comment: Yeah, that is doable. Thank you again!

Comment: What if my minus function change to `minus <- function(a, b, c)`? Your solution does not seem to work.

Comment: You might need something with `do.call` instead of `Reduce`. Not in front of my computer right now...

Comment: I have tried with `do.call`, but it is a little weird. Can you please help me again? Thanks.

Comment: @Nal-rA, What are the functions you're likely to use? You can redefine `minus` as follows: `minus <- function(...) Reduce("-", list(...))`. Then, change the last line in `myFunc` to: `copy(indt)[, new := do.call(FUN, .SD), .SDcols = sapply(dots, deparse)][]`.

Comment: What if the `minus` function is something like, `calculate <- function(x, y, z) x + y - z`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `do.call`:

```
myFunc <- function(dt, FUN, ...){
  arg.names <- as.character(match.call()[-(1:3)])
  copy(dt)[, "new" := do.call(FUN, lapply(arg.names, function(x) get(x)))]
}
#test
myFunc(dt, minus, first, second)
#   first second new
#1:     5      1   4
#2:     6      2   4
#3:     7      3   4
```