# Error in `[.default`(data, subgroups[[1]]) : invalid subscript type 'symbol'

Tags: r

I want to plot a Treemap using treemapify library. As you scan see here http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html, I just copy paste the example done in the above website.

It's really weird, that I get error here:

```
treeMapCoordinates <- treemapify(proglangs,
                                 area = "value",
                                 fill = "parent",
                                 label = "id",
                                 group = "parent")
```

the error is:

> Error in treemapify(proglangs, area = "value", fill = "parent", label
>   = "id",  :    unused arguments (fill = "parent", label = "id", group = "parent")

So I research a solution  and I find this one :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270397/unused-arguments-in-r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270397/unused-arguments-in-r)

Then I did as proposed, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)


    myfunction<-function(data,area,subgroup,subgroup2,...)
    {
     return(treemapify(data,area,subgroup,subgroup2))
    }



myfunction(data=proglangs,
           area="value",
           subgroup="parent",
           subgroup2="id",
           subgroup3="parent")
```

But I get another error:

> Error in `[.default`(data, subgroups[[1](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html)]) :    invalid subscript type
>   'symbol'

How do I resolve this, please?
thank you in advance!

Comment: what is `class(proglangs)`? It should be `data.frame` (or I assume have `inherits(proglangs, 'data.frame') == TRUE`)

Comment: @MichaelChirico, yes it is a `data.frame`