# Is it possible to supply unused arguments to do.call?

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following function:

```
a <- function(p, q){p * q}
```

And I want to use that function in a dynamic `do.call()`statement:

```
do.call("a", list(p = 3, q = 3))
```

That works fine.

But when using dynamic function name to do the do.call-call on, the required arguments in `list()` change.

```
do.call("a", list(p = 3, q = 3, f = 3))
```

This throws an error, since f is not needed function `a`. f is however an argument to a later function used in the dynamic do.call setup.

**Is it possible to allow for arguments that are not needed in a particular function called by do.call but will be needed when the function changes?**

Example:

```
a <- function(p, q){p * q}
b <- function(m, n){paste(m, n)}

funs <- c("a", "b")

for(i in funs){
do.call(i, list(p = 3, q = 3, m = "Yes", n = "No")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unused arguments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270397/unused-arguments-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

There exists a modified version of `base::do.call()`. `R.utils::doCall()` has an argument `.ignoreUnusedArgs` set to `TRUE` by default. Then one can supply more inputs than required to some function in `R.utils::doCall(.fun, args = list(...))` without it throwing an error of unused arguments.

That resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can subset the list with `formalArgs`.

```
a <- function(p, q){p * q}
b <- function(m, n){paste(m, n)}

funs <- c("a", "b")
for(i in funs){
  do.call(i, list(p = 3, q = 3, m = "Yes", n = "No")[formalArgs(i)])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe use the `...` argument in your functions. It can be usefull if you do not want to rely on other packages or use your function outside of `do.call`.

Example:

```
a <- function(p, q, ...){p * q}
```

Output:

```
> a(p = 4, q = 2, f = 1)
[1] 8
```

And here it is with your example:

```
a <- function(p, q, ...){p * q}
b <- function(m, n, ...){paste(m, n)}

funs <- c("a", "b")

for(i in funs){
  print(do.call(i, list(p = 3, q = 3, m = "Yes", n = "No"))) # had to edit it to make a "printable" output for SO
}
```

Output:

```
> for(i in funs){
+   print(do.call(i, list(p = 3, q = 3, m = "Yes", n = "No")))
+ } 
[1] 9
[1] "Yes No"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work for you but you don't need named arguments necessarily. You can pass the arguments by position

```
funs <- list("a", "b")
args <- list(list(3, 3), list('Yes', 'No'))

Map(function(x, y) do.call(x, y), funs, args)

#[[1]]
#[1] 9

#[[2]]
#[1] "Yes No"
```

Comment: Right..., I figured that would not work for my case unfortunately, since then again I would have to supply a selection of arguments by position... I wanted to simply supply every possible argument and let only those be used that are needed by the functions I'm iterating through.